# Questions about create table in sqlite3 of python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 with Python 2.7. I am learning how to create table in a database, so when I want to see whether it is created or not I use command `.tables` but that gives me an error:

> invalid syntax

Here is the code

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('raman.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE table new(ID INT NOT NULL)")
```

Comment: *Where* do you use `.tables`?

Comment: There should be a *master table* in your database containing info on the tables the database contains, the variable types, etc. Try querying that one for `names` if I remember correctly

Comment: i open sqlite3 and use .tables there

Comment: So the code that gives you the error is not the code you have posted here. This is a problem. Post the code that fails.

Comment: or i will run above commands in python 2.7 and after that if i want to see that it is create or not, i use .tables. THere it gives me invalid syntex

Comment: Note that you have to `commit` your changes when creating tables. Add `conn.commit()` and `conn.close()` after the posted code and run it again

Comment: Ev.Kounis i am using this same code in python2.7 but can't use .tables

Comment: okay. Let me do it!

Comment: Ev.Kounis i tried it! Not getting. i think you didn't get my question. after making the table in my database i want to see that it is created or not. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just execute:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'").fetchall()
```

It will give you tables infor:

```
[(u'table', u'new', u'new', 2, u'CREATE TABLE new(ID INT NOT NULL)')]
```

**Update:**
Put below code in you py file:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('raman.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE table new(ID INT NOT NULL)")
print c.execute("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'").fetchall()  #check table info new
c.execute("CREATE table Raman(ATOMIC NUMBER INT, SYMBOL TEXT, ROW INT , COLUMN INT)")
c.execute("INSERT INTO Raman VALUES(1,'H',1,'1')")
conn.commit()
print c.execute("select * from Raman").fetchall() #get data from table Raman
conn.close()
```

Run the py file in your terminal, it will print:

```
[(u'table', u'new', u'new', 2, u'CREATE TABLE new(ID INT NOT NULL)')]
[(1, u'H', 1, 1)]
```

Comment: In terminal if write the codes its working! But when i write this editor and run the file in terminal, it doesnt work.                                                     import sqlite3
     
conn = sqlite3.connect('raman.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'").fetchall()

conn.commit()                                                                                                             
conn.close()

Comment: please note that you have already created the table in `raman.db`, try with a new db like `raman1.db` ,  or drop the table.

Comment: actually it should shoe me the table , as i ryn this command it gives nothing.  i am writing in gedit editor.

Comment: Okay. That's perfect. Learned to drop also

Comment: Now I have added 4 columns in my table.                  c.execute("CREATE table Raman(ATOMIC NUMBER INT, SYMBOL TEXT, ROW INT , COLUMN INT)") and I want to insert values for them in the table so I am writing                              c.execute("INSERT INTO new VALUES(1,'H',1,'1')");                                                  After this if I print the table its not showing me the inserted values

Comment: @HimanshuPareek after you insert values into table `Raman`, you have to use select to get the data from the table, check updated.

Comment: @Tiny.D I think that a `commit` may be required for that database update to be retained.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony you are right, added the `commit` and `close`